Jest test failing due to undefined logger property TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
I'm attempting to mock a signup flow using Jest in Node.js with ts-jest. However, when running the test, it fails with the error:
'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'logger')'
Here's the relevant function code:
Test file:
import Hapi, { ReqRefDefaults } from '@hapi/hapi';
import "reflect-metadata";
import AuthController from '../../controllers/AuthController';
import { IdentityService } from '../../services/IdentityService';
import { SignUpRequest } from '../../interfaces/requests/SignUpRequest';
import { AuthResponse } from '../../interfaces/responses/AuthResponse';

// Mock IdentityService
jest.mock('../../services/IdentityService');

// eslint-disable-next-line max-lines-per-function
describe('AuthController', () => {

  let authController: AuthController;
  let mockIdentityService: jest.Mocked<IdentityService>;
  let mockRequest: Partial<Hapi.Request>;
  let mockResponseToolkit: Partial<Hapi.ResponseToolkit>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockIdentityService = new IdentityService() as jest.Mocked<IdentityService>;
    authController = new AuthController(mockIdentityService);
    mockRequest = { };
    mockResponseToolkit = { };
  });

  describe('signUp', () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-nested-callbacks
    it('should return successful response when sign up is successful', async () => {
      const signUpRequest: SignUpRequest = { email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password123', confirmPassword: 'password123' };
      const expectedResponse: AuthResponse = { email: 'test@example.com', tokens: {
        accessToken: 'sampleAccessToken',
        idToken: 'sampleIdToken',
        refreshToken: 'sampleRefreshToken',
        expiresIn: 3600, // Sample value for expiration time in seconds
      }
    };
      mockIdentityService.signUp.mockResolvedValue(expectedResponse);

      const response = await authController.signUp(mockRequest as Hapi.Request, mockResponseToolkit as Hapi.ResponseToolkit);
      expect(response).toEqual(expectedResponse);
      expect(mockIdentityService.signUp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(signUpRequest);
    });
  });

});

Controller
import { AuthRequest } from '@app/interfaces/requests/AuthRequest';
import { MFAChallengeRequest } from '@app/interfaces/requests/MFAChallengeRequest';
import { RefreshTokenRequest } from '@app/interfaces/requests/RefreshTokenRequest';
import { SignUpRequest } from '@app/interfaces/requests/SignUpRequest';
import { IdentityService } from '../services/IdentityService';
import Hapi from '@hapi/hapi';
import { inject, injectable } from 'inversify';
import BaseController from './BaseController';

/**
 *The Authentication Controller
 */
@injectable()
export default class AuthController extends BaseController {
 
  private identityService: IdentityService;

  constructor(@inject(IdentityService) identityService: IdentityService) {
    super();
    this.identityService = identityService;
  }

  public async signUp(request: Hapi.Request, h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit): Promise<Hapi.ResponseObject> {
    try {
      return this.buildResponse(h, await this.identityService.signUp(request.payload as SignUpRequest));
    } catch (error) {
      return this.handleErrors(h, error);
    }
  }

In basecontroller file we have a function as below. Where the error is actually throwing.
protected handleErrors(h: Hapi.ResponseToolkit, error: Error | string | unknown): Hapi.ResponseObject {
    let customError = { statusCode: StatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message: 'Internal Server Error' };
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      customError = this.getErrorDetails(error);
    }
    // Log the error
    h.request.logger.error(error);

    return h
      .response(this.formatResponseData(customError.statusCode, null, customError.message, error))
      .code(customError.statusCode);
  }

It throws following error:

This is how logger config is specified
logger: {
   .....
    level: {
      doc: 'The level of logging to be done',
      format: ['fatal', 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug', 'trace'],
      default: 'info',
      env: 'LOGGER_LEVEL',
    },
  },

Service function
.......
public async signUp(signUpRequest: SignUpRequest): Promise<AuthResponse> {
    await this.createUser(signUpRequest);
    await this.setUserPassword(signUpRequest);
    const response = await this.initiateAuthentication(
      { USERNAME: signUpRequest.email, PASSWORD: signUpRequest.password },
      AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH,
    );
    return this.extractSignUpResponse(signUpRequest.email, response);
  }
......

I've tried adding a mock like this and several other suggestions I found online, but nothing seems to work:
request:
      {logger: {
        level:jest.fn(),
        error: jest.fn(),
        debug: jest.fn(),
        fatal: jest.fn(),
        warn: jest.fn(),
        info: jest.fn(),
        trace: jest.fn(),
        silent: jest.fn(),
      } as Partial<never>,
    }

How can I properly mock the logger property in my Jest tests to prevent this error or is it something else?
